# Disable or custime formats preview

Tags: tinymce-4

On TinyMCE the formats previews consider the CSS class definition. But it's annoying in some cases, for instance, when the *font-color* is white. So I like to replace it to a custom color **only** on preview (or just disable it function), but keeping white color on real text.

**How it works now:**

[image]

**How I like it to works:**

[image]